# Securing system-generated nodes in firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I've been going through the rules guide but haven't found an answer to this.

App users are able to submit "scores" of different types, which are then processed in JS and written to a "ranking" node. I have it set up so that every time a new score is submitted, the rankings are automatically recalculated and a new child is written if the user doesn't exist or updated if the user exists.

My question is how to secure this "ranking" node. Everyone should be able to read it, nobody except the system should be able to write it. This would prevent people from submitting their own rankings and aggregate scores.

**EDIT**

This is the operation:

```
Ref.child('rankings').child(uid).once('value', function (snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        snapshot.ref().update(user); //user object created upstream
                    } else {
                        var payload = {};
                        payload[uid] = user;
                        snapshot.ref().parent().update(payload);
                    }
                });
```

How would I add custom authentication to this call? Also, since I'm using AngularJS, is there any way to hide this custom token or would I have to route it through a backend server?

Answer (score 0):

The key part of your problem definition is:

> only the system should be able to write it.

This requires that you are able to recognize "the system" in your security rules. Since Firebase security is user-based, you'll have to make your "system" into a user. You can do this by either recording the `uid` from a regular user account or by minting a custom token for your "system".

Once you have that, the security for your `ranking` node becomes:

```
".read": true,
".write": "auth.uid == 'thesystem'"
```

In the above I assume you mint a custom token and specify `thesystem` as the `uid`.

Comment: That's kind of what I figured. I've updated my question with a few more details, do you know how I would do that? Thanks

Comment: Generating a custom token requires the use of your Firebase secret, which you should never have in client-side code. So: indeed it requires a server. But I assume that "the system" already implies that you have code that runs in a trusted environment. If it doesn't, then you can still record the `uid` of your trusted code and take the other approach I suggested. They're pretty much the same from a security rules perspective.

Comment: Right now there is no server, so I don't have a trusted environment. What do you mean by "you can still record the `uid` of your trusted code and take the other approach I suggested"? How would I write to that node specifically with that token? Would I create the token in my firebase dashboard? As far as I understand, the auth variable on that page would be the one for the logged on user (page is only accessible to authenticated users)

Comment: If you don't have a trusted environment, then what does "the system" in your problem mean? Where does this system code run?

Comment: I should have been clearer. All the code is client-side. When I was referring to "the system", I meant the node was not accessible to the users through any other operations/forms. It was just written to as part of the code flow (or in the process of script execution).